# Article tab missing from community

Tags: community, knowledge, community-builder

I have created a community for testing purpose. I could see article tab present in community but that is missing in my case. I googled as well but could not make it work. I want article tab present next to Discussion tab

[image]

want to do like this
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Your question is a bit unclear to me - where and when did you see the *Article* tab present, if you do not see it now?

Comment: Edited in question. I dont see any article tab in community but i want to have one like in the picture above